# GROUP BY on subquery not returning any results

Tags: sql, sql-server

First a bit of background of what I am trying to do:

Time is booked against Jobs and Jobs are organised into Job Groups and I am trying to calculate the hours recorded on a Job Group level.

The issue is how the hours are stored, using "10,000 feet" if anyone knows the system.

For each Job+User+Day there are TWO lines, one showing scheduled hours and the other showing 'actual' hours; although if the user did not confirm their scheduled hours (most do not if there is no difference) then the actual hours are NULL and the scheduled hours are the ones which need to be used.

So the best way to work this is to group these two lines together and when actual hours are NULL use the scheduled hours instead.

On its own the subquery in this full query works fine and shows the correct number of hours.

When placed in the larger query it shows null results; remove the GROUP BY in the subquery and it shows the data but does NOT calculate the scheduled hours into the total when actual is NULL.

I know the answer is in this query, but I am going around and around in circles with it.

Any advice to make me think about this from a different approach will be most welcome.

```
SELECT
    g1.om_number AS "Job Group Number",
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN SUM(tkte2.TimeEntries_Hours) IS NOT NULL
                THEN SUM(tkte2.TimeEntries_Hours)
                ELSE
                (
                    CASE
                        WHEN SUM(tkte2.TimeEntries_Scheduled_Hours) IS NOT NULL
                        THEN SUM(tkte2.TimeEntries_Scheduled_Hours)
                        ELSE 0
                    END
                )
            END
        FROM TenK.TimeEntries AS tkte2
        INNER JOIN TenK.Projects AS tkp2 ON tkp2.Projects_Id=tkte2.TimeEntries_Assignable_Id
        INNER JOIN om.Job AS j2 ON tkp2.Projects_Code=j2.om_number
        WHERE j2.om_jobGroup_id=g1.om_id
        GROUP BY tkte2.TimeEntries_Assignable_Id,tkte2.TimeEntries_User_Id,tkte2.TimeEntries_Date
    ) AS "Hours"
FROM om.jobGroup AS g1
INNER JOIN om.Project AS p1 ON g1.om_project_id=p1.om_id
WHERE (CONVERT(date, p1.om_creationDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND CONVERT(date,'2019-12-31 23:59:59'))
AND g1.om_number='TESTJOB-01'
```

Comment: Tip of today: `COALESCE()`!

Comment: So a SUM(COALESE((SELECT SUB1), (SELECT SUB 2),0)) ?

Hmmmm, I hadn't thought of that! I'll give that a go; thanks! :)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query uses some non-standard functions). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 I could not find it in the tag options.

I think the only non-standard in my original query was the CONVERT and that was used as the dates are in text field format with  say +0000 for UTC time etc appended to the end. so I converted to dates to do a BETWEEN more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have optimized your query a little using OUTER APPLY, and by making sure to include the necessary group(able) fields.

The query is much more simplier and cleaner.

Btw, make sure that `(j2.om_jobGroup_id = g1.om_id)` is matching, otherwise it will return empty.

```

```
SELECT
    g1.om_number AS [Job Group Number]
    , COALESCE(H.TimeEntries_Hours_SUM, H.TimeEntries_Scheduled_Hours_SUM) AS Hours
FROM om.jobGroup AS g1
INNER JOIN om.Project AS p1 ON g1.om_project_id=p1.om_id
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT tkte2.TimeEntries_Assignable_Id
        , tkte2.TimeEntries_User_Id
        , tkte2.TimeEntries_Date
        , SUM(tkte2.TimeEntries_Hours) AS TimeEntries_Hours_SUM
        , SUM(tkte2.TimeEntries_Scheduled_Hours) AS TimeEntries_Scheduled_Hours_SUM
    FROM TenK.TimeEntries AS tkte2
    INNER JOIN TenK.Projects AS tkp2 ON tkp2.Projects_Id = tkte2.TimeEntries_Assignable_Id
    INNER JOIN om.Job AS j2 ON tkp2.Projects_Code=j2.om_number
    WHERE (j2.om_jobGroup_id = g1.om_id)
    GROUP BY tkte2.TimeEntries_Assignable_Id, tkte2.TimeEntries_User_Id, tkte2.TimeEntries_Date
) H
WHERE (CONVERT(date, p1.om_creationDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND CONVERT(date,'2019-12-31 23:59:59'))
    AND g1.om_number='TESTJOB-01';
```

```

Comment: This returns the correct result - thanks! - I'll see if I can use it in the full query without any explosions :)

Comment: you should accept this answer @StevenW if it solved your issue.

Comment: Always use OUTER APPLY next time over column based query. There is significant impact if you are profiling it. Cheers!